# Graphics 2D to label a shape with a variable name

Tags: java, graphics

I have implemented Graphics 2D into a JPanel and have got it tot draw a cirlce on it. However, I want to be able to call the 2D shapes later to be able to move them. How would I do such a thing? I tried declaring it as a variable but I don't know how, any help would be great, thanks.

```
package com.aqagame.harrykitchener;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Game 
{



    public Game()
    {

        JFrame window = new JFrame ("Main Game");
        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1))
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
        };



        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);
        window.setSize(700, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Game();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code above that draws a circle.

Answer (score 1):

A first step could be an own class that is responsible for painting the game contents. (Solving this with an anonymous inner class does not scale so well).

The shapes that you want to paint could then reside in a `List` that you can simply iterate over to paint them.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Game 
{
    public Game()
    {

        JFrame window = new JFrame ("Main Game");
        JPanel firstPanel = new GamePanel();

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);
        window.setSize(700, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Game();
            }
        });

    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel
{
    private final List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    GamePanel()
    {
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(10,20,30,40));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

        for (Shape shape : shapes)
        {
            g2d.draw(shape);
        }
    }

}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** As the name suggests, this should become a "Game". You will most likely run into **severe difficulties** when you continue like that. Stackoverflow is not an "answer generating machine", and a game can not be programmed by trial and error, but involves some *planning*. For example, you could now easily pick the shapes with the mouse (using a MouseListener and the `shape.contains(mousePosition)` method), but dragging them around or even just painting them with different colors would require some larger infrastructure. For example, you should consider something like a `GameEntity` class that encapsulates the entities that appear in your game etc.